# OpenCV & PHP & XAMPP

Tags: php, windows, linux, opencv, xampp

guys!
I've noticed that here are a lot of people who are familiar with OpenCV and PHP, so I would be very thankful if you could answer some of my questions.
At the moment I am working on my diploma paper and the topic is Inpainting on Web.
I have made the application for Inpainting on my own in OpenCV. It is a console application.
Now I would like to know how I could connect my application with PHP and everything together in order to make it start working on my computer via the XAMPP program?
I’ve found on the internet that .dll file could be made from the applications in the OpenCV. 
I have also read that the .dll file can be connected via PHP. Could that work out?
Do you have any another suggestion? A piece of advice? Tutorial? Anything.
And is it possible that the linux user uses windows .dll file in that case?
Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I would like to know how I could connect my application with PHP and everything together in order to make it start working on my computer via the XAMPP program`

A. my Advice is stick to your console application i just call it form PHP using `exec` http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php or `system` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php in PHP .. This is be much more easy for you and faster

B. Instead of writing your own php .dll extension i suggest you use already existing one  http://code.google.com/p/pecl-win/downloads/detail?name=php_facedetect-1.0.1-5.3-ts.dll&can=2&q= .... writing PHP extensions is another ball game

C. If you want to use a pure PHP implementation which is relatively very slow http://www.xarg.org/project/php-facedetect/

D. Another Option is using https://github.com/mgdm/OpenCV-for-PHP ( This would also work for linux users)

I hope this helps

Thanks
:)

Comment: Thanks, this will help me a lot. A few days ago, I saw that PHP-Facedetect project. And I tried to understand source code. And the way of connecting php and OpenVC. Now I'll try another approach. 
Tnx a lot.

Comment: Sorry about unfinished comment.

Comment: I think I'll try that first one, if that don't work for me, I'll try last one.

Comment: If any one works for you .. don't forget to accept so that we can know is resolved

Comment: I stick to Baba first advice. I make inpainting console application and just call it form PHP using exec function. Work nice. Code is very simple. Console application automatic take two images for input and in few sec return inpainted image. Tnx

Comment: how to implement option number 4 "D"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. You have a console application and you want to create a php web interface for it? Then all you need is the exec function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

More on system program execution: http://php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php

Comment: Yes. I have working console application and I want create web site so that Inpainting application will be available for everyone.
Tnx